# Why in C++ function boost::algorithm::join_if a std::bad_cast exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, join, boost, string-algorithm

I found a problem in my code. When I use boost::algorithm::join it works normally, but when I use boost::algorithm::join_if a bad_cast is thrown. My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;


main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    list<string> players;
    players.push_back("ProPlayer98");
    players.push_back("King of Darkness");
    players.push_back("Noob999");
    players.push_back("Daily Queen");

    cout << boost::algorithm::join(players, ", ") << endl; // it works
    cout << boost::algorithm::join_if(players, ", ", boost::is_alpha()) << endl; // bad_cast
}
```

The output of my program is:

```
ProPlayer98, King of Darkness, Noob999, Daily Queen
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Abort trap (core dumped)
```

I have used some times boost::algorithm functions to play with text, few times I was using 
[predicates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/quickref.html#id3186736), but none of problems like that ever occurred.

I even tried to replace const char* to std::string:

```
cout << boost::algorithm::join_if(players, string(", "), boost::is_alpha()) << endl;
```

but problem is still the same.

**EDIT:**
I would like a solution which works also in C++ older than C++11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::is_alpha` is for characters

Use like following:-

```
cout << boost::algorithm::join_if(players, ", ",
                          [](const std::string & s){
                          return boost::all(s,boost::is_alpha()); 
                          }) << endl;
```

Here obviously, you won't get any output as space `' '` and numerals are present in `players`.

Use `boost::alnum()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Thanks to you I found a solution in older C++ standard, but it is completely not readable:
    typedef boost::algorithm::detail::is_classifiedF ClassifiedF;
    join_if(players, "/", boost::bind(boost::all<string, ClassifiedF>, _1, boost::is_alpha() ) );